# Android application is crashing because of title in toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a problem with toolbar's title in my main activity of my training application. I'm building a app with the main parent activity (ChooseActivity) in which I can press two buttons to relocate myself in other two childs (GroupsActivity and AddGroupActivity).I want to add toolbar to everyone with it's own title. Additionaly I add UpButtons to every child activity. I set title with the label param in Android Manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hfad.singleton">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ChooseActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddGroupActivity"
        android:label="@string/add_group"
        android:parentActivityName="com.hfad.singleton.ChooseActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.hfad.singleton.ChooseActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GroupsActivity"
        android:label="@string/groups"
        android:parentActivityName="com.hfad.singleton.ChooseActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.hfad.singleton.ChooseActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

It works perfectly for my child activities, but ChooseActivity doesn't show any title. When i'm trying to solve it with adding methods like toolbar.setTitle or getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My app") my application is get compiled but crashing from the start of running. I have no idea how to deal with it. Below I insert code of activity classes

ChooseActivity class :

```
public class ChooseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose);
        //Creating of toolbar with title App Name
        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        //Adding butttons with listeneres
        Button addGroup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_group);
        Button groups = (Button) findViewById(R.id.groups);
        addGroup.setOnClickListener(this);
        groups.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.add_group:
                Intent intentAddGroup = new Intent(this, AddGroupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentAddGroup);
                break;
            case R.id.groups:
                Intent intentGroups = new Intent(this, GroupsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentGroups);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

AddGroupActivity class :

```
public class AddGroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_group);
        //Creating of toolbar with title Add Group
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        //Enable Up Button
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

GroupsActivity class :

```
public class GroupsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_groups);
        //Creating of toolbar with title Add Group
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        //Enable Up Button
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

toolbar layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

xml of main ChooseActivity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.hfad.singleton.ChooseActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="@string/add_group"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/groups"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="227dp"
    android:text="@string/groups"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: post your crash log..

Comment: I recommend you use separate id names for your toolbars in each activity. Sometimes they conflict with each other if all have same names.

Comment: Ok, in my project i'm using tollbar layout and put it with include tag, just like that. Can I keep it in my project, as I don't want to duplicate the same code. I added xml in my post

Comment: The `id` on the `<include>` overrides the `id` on the root `View` in the included layout. Your `Toolbar` has ID `include` in `ChooseActivity`. Either remove the `id` on the `<include>`, or change your `findViewById()` call to use `R.id.include`. You likely won't need the `setTitle()` call, then, since the `Toolbar` will be correctly set as the support `ActionBar`.